# Is there anyway I can use Strict-Transport security

Tags: ssl, https, strict-transport-security

Is there any way to use a Strict-Transport security header on a site but still have non-ssl sub-domains?

Comment: It would appear not: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161677/can-i-use-hsts-with-mixed-http-https-subdomains/161680#161680

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set `Strict-Transport-Security` header without `includeSubDomains`. For example if you set `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000` on `https://example.com`, then browsers won't enforce HTTPS for `nonsslsub.example.com`.